# WSO2AM does not generate SOAP envelop in case of fault

Tags: api, soap, fault, wso2-api-manager

Version: 1.8.0

In case of faults, for instance "Authentication Failure" the WSO2AM generates the soap Fault, but the response does not include the soap Envelop.

Request:

```
POST /myapi/1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: ""

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://test.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:search>
        <searchString>1234</searchString>
      </test:search>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8

<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <faultcode xmlns:axis2ns36="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">axis2ns36:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Authentication Failure</faultstring>
    <detail>Access failure for API: /rest/bfo/mycase, version: 1.0 with key: null</detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Without the Envelop the client will fail to read the fault message. Looks like the issues is introduced in 1.8.0 and earlier versions responds with valid soap Envelop.

Answer (score 0):

In the fault sequence (/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/fault.xml)content type of out going fault message is set to application/xml

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

If you want to get the soap message set it to **text/xml**

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```